# Java Swing : how to customize the JList's items?

Tags: java, android, swing, awt, jlist

I am new to `Swing` framwork. And I have the following list to design..

[image]

Is there any way by which we can have customized list items in `JList`? Like writing custom `Adapter` in `Android`, which has a method `getView()` which will return the `View` to be shown as ListItem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need a custom renderer. You can either use a [`DefualtListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) which uses a `JLabel` as the rendering component, or you can create a custom `ListCellRenderer` where you can specify the rendering the component by extending the component and impelenting `ListCellRenderer`.

You can see more [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). The link is to the "How to Use Comboboxes" tutorial, but comboboxes and `JLists` use the same type renderer.

The basic concept you will find is that you will have to override the method

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                                   JList list,
                                   Object value,
                                   int index,
                                   boolean isSelected,
                                   boolean cellHasFocus) {
```

for either a custom `ListCellRenderer` or for a `DefaultListCellRenderer`. The Value will return the value of each list item. A list item can be an object, say a `Person` with fields `id` and `name`. So you would case the value to `Person` and use the necessary fields to render the component.

```
Person person = (Person)value;
// renderer the component using Person values
// lastly return the component.
```

So basically just break it down to "how would you renderer one of the cells?" What components would you use? Then just implement the renderer class/method

- See search for [ListCellRenderer questions](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ITZrU7TxF8LJuASYqYKIDg#q=site%3astackoverflow.com+listcellrenderer)
- See search for [DefaultListCellRenderer questions](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ITZrU7TxF8LJuASYqYKIDg#q=site%3astackoverflow.com+defaultlistcellrenderer)